# Print the value of button into text

Tags: button, text, insert

well...I want to insert the value of buttons into text input when it is clicked but js returns me 'undefined' for buttons . It looks like that I want to make calculator , yes but the first step in making calculator is to insert the value of buttons into text .

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>My Calculator</title>
    <style type="text/css">

    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function action(){
            /* This is for testing the function to run
            alert('Successful!');*/
            var val = document.getElementsByName('num').value;
            document.getElementById(/*'result' or 'answer'*/).innerHTML= val;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id="result" type="text" readonly /><br/>
    <button name="num" value="1" onclick="action()">1</button>
    <button name="num" value="2" onclick="action()">2</button>
    <button name="num" value="3" onclick="action()">3</button>
    <button name="operand">+</button><br/>
    <button name="num" value="4" onclick="action()">4</button>
    <button name="num" value="5" onclick="action()">5</button>
    <button name="num" value="6" onclick="action()">6</button>
    <button name="operand">-</button><br/>
    <button name="num" value="7" onclick="action()">7</button>
    <button name="num" value="8" onclick="action()">8</button>
    <button name="num" value="9" onclick="action()">9</button>
    <button name="operand">*</button><br/>
    <button name="operand">C</button>
    <button name="num" value="0" onclick="action()">0</button>
    <button name="operand">=</button>
    <button name="operand">/</button>
    <h1 id="answer"></h1>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try like this,

html

```
<button name="num" id="9" value="9" onclick="action(9)">9</button>
```

script

```
    function action(id){
      /* This is for testing the function to run
      alert('id!');*/

      var val = document.getElementById(id).value;

      document.getElementById('result').value += val;
    }
```

also you are using same name for multiple elements

Comment: yes . I tried but not solved yet . you can send me a complete code for me maybe my problem solved